# Plotting more than 2 graphs on one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to see how spoken-word and read-word frequency correlate with performance on a word game. here is my reproducible sample:

```
    #Word Freq READ####
    Master_error_analysis_READ <- structure(list(Target = c("BABY", "BAGEL", "BANDAGE", "BANJO", 
"CARRIAGE", "CARROT", "CHICKEN", "CHIPMUNK", "CITY", "COBRA", 
"COCOA", "FAIRY", "FERRET", "GARBAGE", "GARLIC", "LETTER", "LETTUCE", 
"LOBSTER", "LOCKER", "MARBLE", "MARKER", "MUFFIN", "MUSHROOM", 
"PASTA", "PEACOCK", "PEANUT", "POSSUM", "PUPPET", "PUPPY", "RACCOON", 
"RACKET", "ROOSTER", "RULER", "SANDAL", "SANDWICH", "SCISSORS", 
"TURKEY", "TURTLE", "WHISTLE", "WIZARD"), Word = c("BABY", "BAGEL", 
"BANDAGE", "BANJO", "CARRIAGE", "CARROT", "CHICKEN", "CHIPMUNK", 
"CITY", "COBRA", "COCOA", "FAIRY", "FERRET", "GARBAGE", "GARLIC", 
"LETTER", "LETTUCE", "LOBSTER", "LOCKER", "MARBLE", "MARKER", 
"MUFFIN", "MUSHROOM", "PASTA", "PEACOCK", "PEANUT", "POSSUM", 
"PUPPET", "PUPPY", "RACCOON", "RACKET", "ROOSTER", "RULER", "SANDAL", 
"SANDWICH", "SCISSORS", "TURKEY", "TURTLE", "WHISTLE", "WIZARD"
), n = c(14L, 6L, 3L, 13L, 4L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 
9L, 11L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 12L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 16L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 
6L, 14L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 7L
), `Frequency (Google Books)` = c(6127799, 29335, 428865, 125242, 
2505730, 215525, 1724136, 30591, 30586130, 69450, 382604, 1082454, 
115446, 674079, 651590, 20168453, 353798, 256454, 271988, 1996235, 
769873, 81982, 270867, 238173, 149644, 277100, 76104, 384574, 
316058, 73050, 268584, 136815, 1659585, 81154, 430627, 511265, 
1763068, 396105, 778168, 309233), Freq = c(6127799, 29335, 428865, 
125242, 2505730, 215525, 1724136, 30591, 30586130, 69450, 382604, 
1082454, 115446, 674079, 651590, 20168453, 353798, 256454, 271988, 
1996235, 769873, 81982, 270867, 238173, 149644, 277100, 76104, 
384574, 316058, 73050, 268584, 136815, 1659585, 81154, 430627, 
511265, 1763068, 396105, 778168, 309233)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
    Target = c("BABY", "BAGEL", "BANDAGE", "BANJO", "CARRIAGE", 
    "CARROT", "CHICKEN", "CHIPMUNK", "CITY", "COBRA", "COCOA", 
    "FAIRY", "FERRET", "GARBAGE", "GARLIC", "LETTER", "LETTUCE", 
    "LOBSTER", "LOCKER", "MARBLE", "MARKER", "MUFFIN", "MUSHROOM", 
    "PASTA", "PEACOCK", "PEANUT", "POSSUM", "PUPPET", "PUPPY", 
    "RACCOON", "RACKET", "ROOSTER", "RULER", "SANDAL", "SANDWICH", 
    "SCISSORS", "TURKEY", "TURTLE", "WHISTLE", "WIZARD"), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
        14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
        25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
        36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -40L), .drop = TRUE))
```

And the code for the graphs

```
#rounding up from 6M (highest value)
coeff_WF_READ <- 10000000
#divided highest value from 10M, then applies same coeff to error analysis
coeff_Error_READ <- 27.742

    ggplot(Master_error_analysis_READ, aes(x = reorder(Word, n))) +
      geom_point(aes(y = n / coeff_Error_READ), size = 4, color = "red")+
      geom_point(aes(y = Freq / coeff_WF_READ), shape=23, fill="blue", size=4) +
      scale_y_continuous(
        name = "Number Correct",
        sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff_WF_READ, name = "Word Frequency"),
        limits = c(NA, 1)
      ) +
      xlab("\nTarget word")+
      theme_bw(14)+
      theme(
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "red", size=13, face="bold"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue", size=13, face="bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)
      ) +
      ggtitle("Error analysis")
```

I am using this same code for the other graph which contains data from spoken words, rather than READ words. I cannot simply merge together more dataframes to `Master_error_analysis_READ` because this results in an error: `Error: suffix must be a character vector of length 2. ℹ suffix is a grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame object of length 2.`

How else can I plot more than two graphs in one? In total there will be three lines here, one for performance, one for Spoken words, and one for Read words.

you can find that dataframe below.

```
Master_error_analysis_Spoken <- structure(list(Target = c("BABY", "BAGEL", "BANDAGE", "BANJO", 
"CARRIAGE", "CARROT", "CHICKEN", "CHIPMUNK", "CITY", "COBRA", 
"COCOA", "FAIRY", "FERRET", "GARBAGE", "GARLIC", "LETTER", "LETTUCE", 
"LOBSTER", "LOCKER", "MARBLE", "MARKER", "MUFFIN", "MUSHROOM", 
"PASTA", "PEACOCK", "PEANUT", "POSSUM", "PUPPET", "PUPPY", "RACCOON", 
"RACKET", "ROOSTER", "RULER", "SANDAL", "SANDWICH", "SCISSORS", 
"TURKEY", "TURTLE", "WHISTLE", "WIZARD"), Word = c("BABY", "BAGEL", 
"BANDAGE", "BANJO", "CARRIAGE", "CARROT", "CHICKEN", "CHIPMUNK", 
"CITY", "COBRA", "COCOA", "FAIRY", "FERRET", "GARBAGE", "GARLIC", 
"LETTER", "LETTUCE", "LOBSTER", "LOCKER", "MARBLE", "MARKER", 
"MUFFIN", "MUSHROOM", "PASTA", "PEACOCK", "PEANUT", "POSSUM", 
"PUPPET", "PUPPY", "RACCOON", "RACKET", "ROOSTER", "RULER", "SANDAL", 
"SANDWICH", "SCISSORS", "TURKEY", "TURTLE", "WHISTLE", "WIZARD"
), n = c(14L, 6L, 3L, 13L, 4L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 
9L, 11L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 12L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 16L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 
6L, 14L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 7L
), `Frequency (TV Corpus)` = c(134992, 1092, 801, 459, 1825, 
1545, 18305, 279, 62051, 967, 1409, 3991, 617, 7496, 1938, 20534, 
1010, 2775, 6017, 1262, 1507, 1863, 1093, 2179, 742, 3391, 741, 
2303, 3527, 845, 1430, 817, 1379, 126, 8080, 2031, 6705, 4702, 
3036, 3237), Freq = c(134992, 1092, 801, 459, 1825, 1545, 18305, 
279, 62051, 967, 1409, 3991, 617, 7496, 1938, 20534, 1010, 2775, 
6017, 1262, 1507, 1863, 1093, 2179, 742, 3391, 741, 2303, 3527, 
845, 1430, 817, 1379, 126, 8080, 2031, 6705, 4702, 3036, 3237
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), groups = structure(list(Target = c("BABY", "BAGEL", "BANDAGE", 
"BANJO", "CARRIAGE", "CARROT", "CHICKEN", "CHIPMUNK", "CITY", 
"COBRA", "COCOA", "FAIRY", "FERRET", "GARBAGE", "GARLIC", "LETTER", 
"LETTUCE", "LOBSTER", "LOCKER", "MARBLE", "MARKER", "MUFFIN", 
"MUSHROOM", "PASTA", "PEACOCK", "PEANUT", "POSSUM", "PUPPET", 
"PUPPY", "RACCOON", "RACKET", "ROOSTER", "RULER", "SANDAL", "SANDWICH", 
"SCISSORS", "TURKEY", "TURTLE", "WHISTLE", "WIZARD"), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
    39L, 40L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -40L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you either include `coeff_WF_Books()` or take out parts of the code that are reproducible?   (eg I think you want `Master_error_analysis_READ` in your code where you have  `Master_error_analysis_Books`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
library(dplyr); 
combo <- bind_rows(
  read = Master_error_analysis_READ,
  spoken = Master_error_analysis_Spoken,
  .id = "source")

ggplot(combo, aes(x = reorder(Word, n))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = n / coeff_Error_READ), size = 4, color = "red")+
  geom_point(aes(y = Freq / coeff_WF_READ, shape = source),  fill="blue", size=4) +
  ...
```

[image]